# Clarification on Scope and Redefinition

Tags: c

Referring to the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
int a;

int main()
{
    int b;
    int b;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler (GCC) complain of redeclaration for only variable 'b' and not 'a'?

> redef.c: In function 'main':
> redef.c:19: error: redeclaration of 'b' with no linkage
>
> redef.c:18: error: previous declaration of 'b' was here

Comment: Just to rule out one totally picky detail: Could this be a unicode issue where the first "a" is latin and the second "a" is cyrillic?

Comment: Yes. The other question referred here more or less touches on the topic of scope. My interest is also on compiler not saying 'redeclaration' on variable 'a'

Comment: Also see this: [In C,why is multiple declarations working fine for a global variable but not for a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15734699/2455888).

Comment: @haccks, Thanks! That question precisely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `a` has external linkage and the standard states (C11, 6.2.2/2):

> An identifier declared in different scopes or in the same scope more than once can be made to refer to the same object or function by a process called linkage. There are three kinds of linkage: external, internal, and none.
>
> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, **each declaration of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object** or function. Within one translation unit, each declaration of an identifier with internal linkage denotes the same object or function. **Each declaration of an identifier with no linkage denotes a unique entity.**

So, because `a` has external linkage, both those declarations refer to the *same* underlying variable. Because `b` has no linkage, the declaration refer to *unique* variables and therefore conflict with each other.

Comment: So which of the two statements defines the variable `a` - the first one?

Comment: I think this quote does not establish the legality or illegality of OP's code. It just means that if the code is legal, then both identifiers denote the same object.

Comment: @Matt, the phrase "if you do A, it means B" very much establishes the legality of A provided B isn't something like "the compiler will generate an error".

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the C99 standard §6.9.2 ¶2

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
>   without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
>   the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative
>   definition. If a translation unit contains one or more **tentative
>   definitions** for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
>   external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
>   as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
>   unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

Therefore, both the statements

```
int a;
int a;
```

constitute tentative definitions. According to the above quoted part, the behaviour is as if
the two statements were replaced by

```
int a = 0;
```

However, `b` defined inside `main` is an automatic variable, i.e., it has automatic storage allocation. There cannot be two definitions of an automatic variable.

Answer (score 0):

`int a; int a;` is a *tentative definition*. From 6.9.2p2:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>   **tentative definition**. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

Tentative definitions are only permitted at file scope.

The reason that `int b; int b;` is illegal is because of 6.7p3:

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier
>   (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space

Identifiers declared within a function and not `static` or `extern` have *no linkage*, this is describd in 6.2.2p6

> The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than
>   an object or a function; an identifier declared to be a function parameter; a block scope
>   identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.